# Wixtoolset: How to show error message or error code at least?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I cant find an example of specifically showing more helpful errors on the "FatalDialog" dialog on a wix installer.

For example, for the error 1603 i get the generic dialog i've designed by following the tutorial here https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/creating-customized-dialog-boxes-wix

The message is so generic that i didnt get: the error code (1603) nor the error message "a restart is required before you can install this..." for example

I've found the error 1603 from looking at the logs generated by using msiexec /l*v

Somebody can point me on how to make a better error dialog with some better output for the user on the actions required ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess my question to a question would be... would a user understand?  I've always written my UI based on the assumption a user won't even read and will just click next next next.  Along those lines I've had people not even read the  install cancelled, completed, failed dialogs and just click close.  The assumption was it must have installed and then they were dissapointed when their app wasn't installed.

I was looking through an MSI log and I'm not aware of the error information even being exposed as properties.  I suppose you could ensure MSI logging is enabled and then use a custom action to parse it from the log.  Perhaps a checkbox that defaults to yes asking if a user would like the log analyzed.  Then post it to a webservice and launch a web page where you could gather the information and do detailed analysis.

Personally I try to have my installs never fail.  Or very very rarely atleast. In my scenario those .01% failures are captured and surfaced through enterprise monitoring / dashboard tools.